# How can I pass environment variable to project which run on EMR Serverless?

Tags: amazon-emr, emr-serverless

In my PySpark project I'm using a python package that uses `Dynaconf` so I need to set the following environment variable - `ENV_FOR_DYNACONF = platform`.
The problem is I don't understand how can I pass this environment variable to the EMR Serverless job run.

I've tried this -

`os.environ['ENV_FOR_DYNACONF'] = platform`

At the beginning of the code, but it didn't work and in any case, I want to understand what is the right way to pass env variables to the EMR.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass environment variables in EMR Serverless, you can use the following spark job properties in `sparkSubmitParameters` :

- `spark.executorEnv.[KEY]`  to pass env variables to the executors.
- `spark.emr-serverless.driverEnv.[KEY]` to pass env variables to the driver.

Example :

```
"sparkSubmitParameters": "--conf spark.emr-serverless.driverEnv.ENV_FOR_DYNACONF=platform"
```

For more information, refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-Serverless-UserGuide/jobs-spark.html